# Is Vaishnava dharma parva a part of Mahabharatha?

Tags: mahabharata, translation

The telugu translation of Mahabharatha is containing an extra parva names Vaishnavadharma parva. It contains 22 chapters in it. It is basically a discussion between Krishna and Yudhishthira. It follows immediatly after [Anugita parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/index.htm) and preceeds before [Asramavasika parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m15/index.htm)

But, English translation in sacred texts does not contain it.

Is that parva a part of Mahabharatha?

Comment: Most probably no.. "The next must be known as the 'Anugita' in which are words of spiritual philosophy. Those that follow are called 'Asramvasa',..." Can u pls match number of chapters in all three parvas, may be  few chapters of Anugita and/or Asramvasa are labelled under new parva..

Comment: @YDS Yeah only last chapter 92 belongs to Vaishnava dharma Parva and 16-91 fall in Anugita Parva. Although there are 22 chapters in Vaishnavadharma parva, numbers are not given to them except the first (92).